# Draw Rectangle in ViewPager

Tags: android, android-canvas

What would be the best to dynamically draw a rectangle in a ViewPager? Can I add a canvas inside the xml that the ViewPager is using? If so, how would it be implemented?

The FragmentActivity:

```
public class Tabs extends FragmentActivity {
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.tabs);
    }
}
```

The FragmentPagerAdapter method I'm using:

```
private class ScreenSlidePagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    public ScreenSlidePagerAdapter(android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public android.support.v4.app.Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return ScreenSlidePageFragment.create(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return NUM_PAGES;
    }
}
```

This is the Fragment that I have for the ViewPager

```
public class ScreenSlidePageFragment extends Fragment {
/**
 * The argument key for the page number this fragment represents.
 */
public static final String ARG_PAGE = "page";
public static TextView personalTextView, cityTextView;

ViewGroup rootView = null;

/**
 * The fragment's page number, which is set to the argument value for {@link #ARG_PAGE}.
 */
private int mPageNumber;
private boolean isExanded;

/**
 * Factory method for this fragment class. Constructs a new fragment for the given page number.
 */
public static Fragment create(int position) {
    ScreenSlidePageFragment fragment = new ScreenSlidePageFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt(ARG_PAGE, position);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}

public ScreenSlidePageFragment() {
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mPageNumber = getArguments().getInt(ARG_PAGE);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout containing a title and body text.

    if(mPageNumber + 1==1){
        rootView = (ViewGroup) inflater
                .inflate(R.layout.fragment_screen_slide_page, container, false);


    }else if(mPageNumber + 1==2){
        rootView = (ViewGroup) inflater
                .inflate(R.layout.fragment_screen_slide_page2, container, false);

    }else if(mPageNumber + 1==3){
        rootView = (ViewGroup) inflater
                .inflate(R.layout.fragment_screen_slide_page3, container, false);

    }else if(mPageNumber + 1==4){
        rootView = (ViewGroup) inflater
                .inflate(R.layout.fragment_screen_slide_page4, container, false);

    }


    return rootView;
}


/**
 * Returns the page number represented by this fragment object.
 */
public int getPageNumber() {
    return mPageNumber;
}
```

}

Below is the fragment_screen_slide_page.xml that I am using:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:mySwitch="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/content"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="158dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="16dp" >

    <!-- Need to add a rectangle here -->
    <!-- This is the rectangle view I'm trying to draw with -->
            <com.draw.DrawBudget
         android:id="@+id/budget"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:gravity="center"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/texttop"
        style="?android:textAppearanceLarge"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="BUDGET PLANNER"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/arrow"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/texttop"
        android:src="@drawable/arrow" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/vnosEmaila"
        android:layout_width="100dip"
        android:layout_height="20dip"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="99dp"
        android:paddingBottom="0dp"
        android:paddingTop="0dp"
        android:text="$60.00"
        android:textSize="12sp" />

     <TextView
         android:id="@+id/textView1"
         style="?android:textAppearanceSmall"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_below="@+id/arrow"
         android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/arrow"
         android:lineSpacingMultiplier="1.2"
         android:paddingTop="2dip"
         android:text="Spending Goal" />

     <com.utility.less.MySwitch
         android:id="@+id/switch2"
         style="@style/mySwitchStyle"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
         android:gravity="center"
         mySwitch:textOff="ON"
         mySwitch:textOn="OFF"
         mySwitch:textOnThumb="false"
         mySwitch:thumb="@drawable/switch_thumb"
         mySwitch:track="@drawable/switch_track" />

     <TextView
         android:id="@+id/days"
         style="?android:textAppearanceSmall"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
         android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
         android:lineSpacingMultiplier="1.2"
         android:paddingTop="2dip"
         android:text="24 days left" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is the custom View that I created to draw a rectangle. It isn't working though.

```
public class DrawBudget extends View {

Paint paint = new Paint();
Canvas mCanvas;

public DrawBudget(Context context) {
super(context);
}

public DrawBudget(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
super(context, attrs);
}   


@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) { 
    mCanvas = canvas;
super.onDraw(canvas);
    paint.setColor(Color.GREEN);
    canvas.drawRect(0, 100, 100, 0, paint);
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to simply override onDraw() and draw your rectangle.  You need to create a Paint object for use during drawing, which you can do in the constructor.

```
private Paint rectColor = new Paint();
rectColor.setColor (...);
```

Then, you need to draw the rect:

```
@Override
protected void  onDraw (Canvas canvas) 
{
  super.onDraw (canvas);
  canvas.drawRect (..., rectColor);
}
```

Comment: Can you explain this some more? Perhaps provide some code if you can?

Comment: Where should the onDraw method go? Should it be in the FragmentPagerAdapter method that is used with the ViewPager, in the Fragment used to inflate the xml screens, in the main FragmentActivity that initiates the ViewPager, or some where else? (see edits above)

Comment: In the view that needs to contain the rectangle.  It depends on how you want the view to show.  If it is to overlay the text and image, then you simply draw it in the RelativeLayout.  If it needs to occupy its own space, you need to make the rectangle a view, itself.

Comment: I created a custom View to draw the Rectangle, but it isn't working (see edits above for complete code)

Comment: I think you need to reverse the parameters: should be left, top, right bottom == 0, 0, 100, 100.